# If $\alpha$ is an angle in a triangle and if $\tan\alpha = 7$, then which of the statements is true?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

If $\alpha$ is an angle in a triangle and if $\tan\alpha = 7$, then which of the following statements is true?

a) $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{6}$

b) $\frac{\pi}{3}<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$

c) There exists no such angle.

d) None of the above.

Since $$\tan\alpha = \frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=7,$$ both $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ should be either negative or positive. This only happens in 1° and 3° quadrant. So both option a) and b) should satisfy this equation since both lie in the first quadrant. But there is only one correct answer.

Comment: Try comparing to the known values  of $\tan{\frac{\pi}{6}}$ and $\tan{\frac{\pi}{3}}$, and recall that tan is an increasing function over the interval (0,\frac{\pi}{2})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider when $\tan(\alpha)>1,$ so this is the same as asking when is $\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}>1.$ Once you find that out, you ask, when is $\tan(x)$ undefined. Your answer lies in between those values.

Comment: $\tan\alpha > 1$ when $\alpha > \pi/4.$ But $\pi/4$ lies between $\pi/6$ and $\pi/3$, so it still lies outside both intervals in a) and b).

Comment: I think you've just provided sufficient reason to conclude that D is correct. Do you agree?

Comment: No, because $\alpha > \pi/4$ can also mean that $\pi/3 < \alpha < \pi/2$. So b) can b) an answer too?

Comment: The other answers address this issue.

Comment: Well, as of now, it stands between b) and d).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\tan\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\sqrt3<7<+\infty=\lim_{\alpha\to\pi/2^-}\tan\left(\alpha\right)$$

Comment: $\tan(\pi/2)$ is undefined. When talking about limits you are correct though. Therefore, -1. If you correct it, I will undo the negative voting. Cheers.

Comment: @Math_QED darn, you beat me to it.  I was typing this on mobile between classes and couldn't fix it up all the way =P

Comment: Well, if I don't know that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})=\sqrt{3}$? Because we are not allowed to have any trigonometric tables on this test.

Comment: @Parseval honestly, I think you should remember your special angles.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is no way around that. Typical that many mathtest test, to a great deal, test your memory skills and not your mathematical skills.

Comment: @Parseval there will be a time when you can approximate trig values by hand... :-)

Comment: When is that time?

Comment: Second year calculus probably.

Answer (score 1):

(1) $\tan{0}=0$

(2) $\tan{\pi/6}=1/\sqrt{3}$

(3) $\tan$ monotonically increases on $[0,\pi/6]$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

We have
$$\tan (\frac {\pi}{3})=\sqrt {3} $$
and
$$\tan(\frac {\pi}{3+3})=\frac{\sqrt {3}}{3} <\sqrt {3}<7$$

and $x\mapsto \tan (x) $ increasing at $[0,\frac {\pi}{2}) $.

$$\frac {\pi}{3}<\alpha <\frac {\pi}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

You continue as follows:

$$\tan{\alpha}=7 \Rightarrow \frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}}=7 \Rightarrow \sin{\alpha}=7\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\alpha}}$$

Noting $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2},$ we square both sides:
$$ \sin^2{\alpha}=49(1-\sin^2{\alpha}) \Rightarrow $$
$$\sin^2{\alpha}=\frac{49}{50} \Rightarrow\sin{\alpha}=\frac{7}{5\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.99 \Rightarrow \frac{\pi}{3}<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Note: $\sin{\alpha}$ increases in $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin{90^\circ}=1.$